# Sony Smartwatch 2 app available when disconnected

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I just started testing to write "apps" for Sony Smartwatch 2.  I noticed that some apps (or extensions) are still able to function and read data stored on the watch itself, and some apps are disabled once the watch is disconnected. Just wondering how to setup the smart extension to be able to use when disconnected?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Weston's answer is correct. However, there is one type of extension that is not totally "disconnected", the notification extensions. The notification that have been transmitted to the watch will be viewable also when the BT connection to the phone is down, but you will of course not be able to get new notifications during this time.

So, Control and Sensor type extensions are definitely offline, but Notification type extensions are semi-online.

Comment: Thank you! So apps like "WatchIt!" is Notification extension? So by default the icon will be Enabled if the extension is declared as notification extension?

Comment: Yes, you could say that.

Answer (score 1):

Only some Sony apps can run on the watch. All other apps run on the phone, which is why the become unavailable when disconnected.